# NoMachine latency is too high even on LAN, what to do?

Tags: mac, vnc, remote, nomachine

I‘ve used an Android phone without WIFI and Data as a router, mirroring screen projection between two computers (Mac remote Win) with NoMachine and VNC. I found NoMachine latency so much higher than VNC that it was unbearable. Is this phenomenon normal? How to solve?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Get a proper with much higher internal throughput.  That will be your best solution.